# Gibbs sampling from posterior distribution using R

Tags: r, gibbs, posterior

New to MCMC.

I have a model, saying
$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\beta_2x_{i2}+\frac{e_i}{\sqrt{\mu}}$$
where $x_{ij}$ are fixed covariates, $e_i\sim N(0,1)$, $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ and $\mu$ are unknown parameters, with the prior distribution for parameters $\beta_i\sim N(0,1)$ and $\mu\sim \Gamma(0.1,0.1)$

Now I need to implement a Gibbs sampling of $(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\mu)$ procedure from the joint posterior distribution with R.

I did some calculation but not sure: is this the posterior distribution?
$$
C\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\beta_0^2}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\beta_1^2}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\beta_2^2}{2}}\right)\mu^{0.1-1}e^{-0.1\mu}
$$
$$
\qquad\qquad
\times\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu}{2}[y_i-(\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\beta_2x_{i2})]^2}
$$

But I still don't know how to derive the posterior distribution, neither do I know how to do the sampling with R. Can anyone give me some references? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your posterior is correct (I edited a missing $\sqrt{}$). Because you are using conjugate priors you actually do not need Gibbs sampling, you can derive exactly the posterior distribution. This is shown for instance in our book, [*Bayesian Core*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441922865), where the entire chapter 3 is dedicated to Gaussian linear regression.

If you really want to run a Gibbs sampler (is this an homework?!), the above posterior is all you need. From there, you extract the terms that depend on $\beta_0$, 
$$
\pi(\beta_0|\beta_{-0},x,\mu)\propto
\exp\left[-\beta_0^2/2-\mu\sum_i \{y_i−(β_0+β_1x_{i1}+β_2x_{i2})\}^2/2\right]
$$
and this gives you a Gaussian distribution with parameters depending on the data and the other parameters. Then you do the same for $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$, again ending up with two Gaussian distributions. Then for $\mu$, where the conditional distribution is then a Gamma distribution. You should find further details, if needed, in any Bayesian book, including [*Bayesian Core*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441922865), [*Monte Carlo Statistical Methods*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919392), and [*Bayesian Data Analysis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488388X).

Comment: this book doesn’t have a french edition?